# SSD(single shot detector)'s default box implementation

Tags: python, deep-learning

I can't understand SSD's default box implementation. Original paper's formula is below;

[image]

`w_k=s_k√a_k`, `h_k=s_k/√a_k`

But many SSD's implementation seems to be different above's formula. For example, [ssd.pytorch](https://github.com/amdegroot/ssd.pytorch/blob/master/layers/functions/prior_box.py);

```py
mean = []
for k, f in enumerate(self.feature_maps):
    for i, j in product(range(f), repeat=2):
        f_k = self.image_size / self.steps[k]
            # unit center x,y
            cx = (j + 0.5) / f_k
            cy = (i + 0.5) / f_k

            # aspect_ratio: 1
            # rel size: min_size
            s_k = self.min_sizes[k]/self.image_size
            mean += [cx, cy, s_k, s_k]

            # aspect_ratio: 1
            # rel size: sqrt(s_k * s_(k+1))
            s_k_prime = sqrt(s_k * (self.max_sizes[k]/self.image_size))
            mean += [cx, cy, s_k_prime, s_k_prime]

            # rest of aspect ratios
            for ar in self.aspect_ratios[k]:
                mean += [cx, cy, s_k*sqrt(ar), s_k/sqrt(ar)]
                mean += [cx, cy, s_k/sqrt(ar), s_k*sqrt(ar)]
# back to torch land
output = torch.Tensor(mean).view(-1, 4)
```

Other [ssd_keras](https://github.com/rykov8/ssd_keras) is;

```py
# define prior boxes shapes
box_widths = []
box_heights = []

for ar in self.aspect_ratios:
   if ar == 1 and len(box_widths) == 0:
        box_widths.append(self.min_size)
        box_heights.append(self.min_size)
   elif ar == 1 and len(box_widths) > 0:
        box_widths.append(np.sqrt(self.min_size * self.max_size))
        box_heights.append(np.sqrt(self.min_size * self.max_size))
   elif ar != 1:
        box_widths.append(self.min_size * np.sqrt(ar))
        box_heights.append(self.min_size / np.sqrt(ar))
box_widths = 0.5 * np.array(box_widths)
box_heights = 0.5 * np.array(box_heights)
```

- Question

  What is `s_k = self.min_sizes[k]/self.image_size` ? What is `self.min_size * self.max_size` ? I can't find formula in original paper.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the answer in github's [issue](https://github.com/sgrvinod/a-PyTorch-Tutorial-to-Object-Detection/issues/48)

UPDATE:

`min_sizes/img_size` and `max_sizes/img_size` mean `s_k` and `s_k+1` respectively. Also, `conv4_3` applies `s_k=0.1` instead of equation(4). Therefore, all of feature maps can't apply equation(4). So I think all of scales are defined as `min_sizes` and `max_sizes` beforehand.